# How to get a specific character using an integer and if...else

Tags: java

We have an assignment about `if...else`. How do I get the character from a string if we input an integer?

This is for **netbeans** since it's the only application that was taught to us.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Enter your word: ");  
String word = scan.nextLine();  
System.out.println("Enter your number: ");  
int num = scan.nextInt();

if (word.charAt(num))  
{  
System.out.println( "Answer is " + word.charAt(0));  
}  
else ( word.length < num)  
{  
System.out.println("number exceeds string length");  

// the if part is where the confusion began  
// index should start from 1 and not 0
```

Expected Output:

> Enter word: Flood Enter number: 2 Answer: l
>
> (If number exceed entered exceeds the output should be)
>
> Enter word: Flood Enter number: 6 number exceeds string length

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: It doesn’t matter that it’s for Netbeans. It’s in Java, so apart from your bug it will work in Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, you name it. It’s nice that you are learning input validation early on.

Answer (score 1):

As `array` index always starts from `0`, you can always subtract by 1 in `num`. Try the code below:

```
//if user enter char at 5 then it will num-1=4
if (word.length() > num-1) 
{
    //value at 4 postion as index starts from 0
    System.out.println( "Answer is " + word.charAt(num-1));  
}
else 
{  
    System.out.println("number exceeds string length");  
}
```

**Output** :

```
Enter your word:                                                                                                              
weeet                                                                                                                         
Enter your number:                                                                                                            
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Answer is t
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I am having difficulty on understanding the array, where to put .length and .charAt. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: great ,if this help you .. please try to accept this answer by clicking on tick symbol :)